# Copying iTunes playlists to external USB flash drive

Tags: itunes, usb-flash-drive

On my Macbook Pro running OSX 10.6.8, is there a way to have my playlists synchronize to a USB flash drive for my car stereo? The flash drive is formatted as FAT32, and I know you can do it in Windows Media Player; however, I have all my playlists set up in iTunes already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I don't know why it didn't work the first time, but I was able to (the second time) just drag the music from my playlist over to the flash drive, and it started copying. Thanks for all the views, sorry if I puzzled anyone